# Как посчитать количество записей в разные даты mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Заголовок немного сумбурный, но я не знаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос. У меня есть таблица со следующей структурой:

[image: структура таблицы]

Мне необходимо написать запрос, который бы посчитал мне для каждого address количество fromwhere по месяцам. Я сделал вот так:

```
SELECT `idinvite`, 
    `address`, 
    `cdate_int`, 
    COUNT(fromwhere) AS `fromwhere` 
FROM `invites_stat` 
WHERE idregion = '11' AND fromwhere != 0  
GROUP BY `idinvite` 
ORDER BY `cdate_int` DESC
```

Но данный запрос суммировал все мои данные вместе и получилось, будто бы все даты в базе - это один месяц. Мне же нужны данные со срезом по дате, чтобы можно было строить графики по ним и т.д, примерно вот так:

```
SELECT Id, 
    address, 
    date (timestamp), 
    (количество записей поля fromwhere за месяц) as fromwhere 
FROM ... 
WHERE ...
```

Как написать такой запрос правильно?

Comment: дак группируйте по году-месяцу, или дате, как вам там надо

Comment: Сгруппируйте по месяцу `GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(cdate_int))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема MySQL - если в группировке отсутствует одно из полей, запрос всё равно отработает и выдаст результат (в отличие от других СУБД).
Нельзя забывать, что сколько в `select` столбцов без агрегирующих функций, столько и столбцов должно быть в `group by`, если хотите получить именно тот результат, который нужен.

Ваш запрос должен быть таким:

```
SELECT `idinvite`, 
    `address`, 
    date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(cdate_int), '%Y-%m-01') as monthdate, 
    COUNT(fromwhere) AS `fromwhere` 
FROM `invites_stat` 
WHERE idregion = '11' AND fromwhere != 0  
GROUP BY `idinvite`, `address`, date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(cdate_int), '%Y-%m-01')
ORDER BY monthdate DESC
```

Функция `date_format` преобразует дату в вид "ГГГГ-ММ-01", т.е. обнуляет дату до месяца, в итоге агрегирование идёт помесячно. Отличие от функции `month(date)` тем, что `date_format` сделает агрегирование по месяцу внутри каждого года, `month(date)` же схлопнет всё помесячно, т.е. если один и тот же месяц был в базе в разных годах, то всё схлопнется просто в один месяц.

Comment: Если Вам не сложно, вы не могли бы пояснить что значит '%Y-%m-01'? Впервые вижу такой паттерн для даты)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев добавил в ответ)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    `idinvite`, 
    `address`,  
     COUNT(`fromwhere`) AS `count`, 
     MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`cdate_int`)) AS `month` 
FROM 
    `invites_stat` 
WHERE 
    `fromwhere` != 0 AND `idregion` = '11'
GROUP BY 
     `address`, `month`
```